# Install both php5-imagick and php7.4-imagick on the same Debian machine?

Tags: debian, php56

When I try to install php7.4-imagick Debian removed the php5-imagick
Is there a way to keep them both - so when I run php5 it can use the php5-imagick version and when I run the php7.4 it will use it's own version ?

looks like both needs imagemagick-common, but different versions.

Comment: PHP 5 reached it's end of life on December 31st, 2018

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

There are several, actually. But The thing is, - you need not only one library, but all of the PHP stack to be version 5.x.
Still doable though.

- using package manager, the only problem is that php5 is obsoleted long ago, so there's no chance to do this using current repositories, but at least it's worth trying playing with repos that still host php5 for necrolegacy addicts.
- using custom installprefix when installing from source. just add `--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.6.40` as first `configure` argument.
- that's actually the exact sweet spot where **docker** comes in hand. I personally would do this using **docker**.